# New custom field visible in Report type, but not visible in Report Builder

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, custom-report-type, report-builder

I have a custom field (cf1) within a custom object (co1) where the field-level security is set to "Read-Only" for all of the Profiles with access to that object. It is a Formula(Number) field. I also have a custom report type (rt1) that has co1 available for the report; and after clicking edit layout, then dragging cf1 to the co1 Field Layout, I clicked save.

Finally, I navigated to the Report tab, and created a new report using rt1 as the Report Type. The Report Type is available, but when I do a quick find search for the cf1, it cannot be found. I'm conducting a search for the field label correctly, but cf1 never shows up. Where else should I look to solve this issue?

Side Note: This field is configured the exact same way in another sandbox, and it is available in Report Builder for the Custom Report Type.

EDIT: Deployment Status is set to 'Deployed'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you make sure the field level security of the Formula field you created is set to Visible ( as the Read only is checked by default to the formula fields ). 
If this works let me know.